# SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, eclipse, sdl

I am following [a tutorial](http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/eclipse/index.php) to set up SDL in Eclipse.

I had to download 7zip to open the tar file.  I used 7 zip to copy all of the files according to the tutorial.  I tried putting a copy of `SDL.dll` in `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32` and also the project folder in my eclipse workspace.

When I try to run the following code:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following compile errors:

```
..\main.cpp:1:21: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory
..\main.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
..\main.cpp:6: error: `SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING' undeclared (first use this function)
..\main.cpp:6: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
..\main.cpp:6: error: `SDL_Init' undeclared (first use this function)
..\main.cpp:9: error: `SDL_Quit' undeclared (first use this function)
```

I tried replacing the include statement with the following:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
```

but that didn't work out either.

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to do step 3 in your tutorial?

From the linked tutorial:

> 3. After that, open the include subfolder in the archive and extract the folder named "SDL" to the MinGW include folder, which should be at C:\MinGW\include.

Answer (score 0):

These compilation errors are a consequence of your compiler not being able to find the SDL header file you're including in your `main.cpp`.

This is happening because you are not telling your compiler where to find the SDL headers. Try passing `-I"path_to_your_SDL_include_directory"` to your compiler.