# SDL.h No such file or directory in VSCode

Tags: c++, sdl-2, undefined-reference

I'm trying to add the relevant `"-I"path_to_your_SDL_include_directory""` as outlined in several similar posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408410/sdl-sdl-h-no-such-file-or-directory). I have tried three approaches;, adding it to tasks.json, Makefile and c_cpp_properties.json.

My file structure is as follows. My main.cpp is in `MyProject/src`. I have copied all the contents of SDL's include folder to `MyProject/lib/SDL2_lib/include` and copied the lib folder to `MyProject/lib/SDL2_lib/lib`. `SDL2.dll` lives in  `MyProject/lib/SDL2_lib`.

The following is a visual summary as well as my code.

[image: File Structure]

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>


const int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Hello SDL WORLD", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI );

    if ( NULL == window )
    {
        std::cout << "Could not create window: " << SDL_GetError( ) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Event windowEvent;

    while ( true )
    {
        if ( SDL_PollEvent( &windowEvent ) )
        {
            if ( SDL_QUIT == windowEvent.type )
            { break; }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit( );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Makefile

```
all:
    g++ -I lib/SDL2_lib/include -Llib/SDL2_lib/lib -o Main src/main.cpp
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-I lib/SDL2_lib/include",
                "-L lib/SDL2_lib/lib",
                "-lmingw32",
                "-lSDL2main",
                "-lSDL2",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/bin\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/lib/SDL2_lib/include"
                        ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-I lib/SDL2_lib/include",
                "-L lib/SDL2_lib/lib",
                "-lmingw32",
                "-lSDL2main",
                "-lSDL2"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Despite all this, I am getting the error:

[image]

Edit: I should also add that adding a random file name instead of `SDL.h` underlines the entire include statement instead of just the end. So clearly, VSCode does know it exists, its just not adding it to the program which is what I'm guessing

Edit2: Running `make` from powershell gives the following error:

[image]

Comment: Is there an `SDL2` folder inside `SDL2_lib/include`? Whats the content of the folder `SDL2_lib/lib`?

Comment: Inside inlcude is all the .h files that comes in the original donwload at ```include/SDL2```. ```SDL2_lib/lb``` is an exact copy of the lib file provided in the default mingw download for sdl2

Comment: Having both a makefile and a task is redundant. Or rather, you can have a task, but it should run the makefile instead of specifying all the compiler flags. *"Running make from powershell gives the following error"* Well, yes, you failed to specify `-l...` in the makefile. *"SDL.h No such file or directory"* I'm not that familiar with the stock C++ extension, but I think you need to add `includePath` to `c_cpp_properties.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that you have two problems.

1. The VSCode's C++ extension complains about the file SDL2.h
2. There's a linking problem when you compile from your Makefile

Let's address the Makefile thing first:

There's a typo in your Makefile, it says `SDL2_lib/libr` instead of `SDL2_lib/lib`.

After fixing that, you must add the libraries to link with. Technically, you only need `libSDL2.la` (assuming dynamic linking) since you already wrote your own `main()` function (therefore you don't need `SDL2main`.

So, the command line in your Makefile should look like this (note how I put the project's files before the libs to guarantee symbols are loaded correctly, this becomes more important when using intermediate files):

```cpp
g++ -Ilib/SDL2_lib/include -Llib/SDL2_lib/lib src/main.cpp \
    -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows \
    -o Main
```

If that doesn't work, please provide the compiler output (as text, not image) but not before trying this:

Option one: Specify the whole library's filename:

```cpp
g++ -Ilib/SDL2_lib/include -Llib/SDL2_lib/lib src/main.cpp \
    -lmingw32 -lSDL2main.la -llibSDL2.la -mwindows \
    -o Main
```

Option two: Link statically (you won't need the DLL)

```
g++ -Ilib/SDL2_lib/include -Llib/SDL2_lib/lib src/main.cpp \
    -lmingw32 lib/SDL2_lib/lib/libSDL2main.a lib/SDL2_lib/lib/libSDL2.a -mwindows \
    -o Main
```

About VSCode:

I don't think there's anything wrong with your configuration. You may want to try switching to backslashes (which should't make a difference anyway) or (yes, for real) reloading VSCode.

Comment: Should have updated yesterday, but yeah, compiling directly from the command line using g++ worked. I didn't end up using Makefile, cpp configs or tasks.json. The next issue I got was needing to define a Macro before the #include, doing this ended up solving the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used Windows and VSCode but I guess you can try

```
g++ -I lib/SDL2_lib/include -Llib/SDL2_lib/lib -lsdl -o Main src/main.cpp
```

or

```
g++ -I lib/SDL2_lib/include -Llib/SDL2_lib/lib -lsdl2 -o Main src/main.cpp
```

Comment: I ran both from the command line and now I'm just getting ```cannot find -lsdl```

Comment: Maybe try `-lSDL` or `-lSDL2` instead? Maybe case matters

Answer (score -1):

There shouldn't be space between flags
ie
"-I lib/SDL2_lib/include" should be "-Ilib/SDL2_lib/include"
"-L lib/SDL2_lib/lib" should be "-Llib/SDL2_lib/lib"

Answer (score -1):

### MacOS

Install the tools and libs

```bash
brew install gcc
brew install sdl2
brew install sdl2_image
```

Create project structure

```bash
mkdir -p game_app/{include,lib,src,build/debug}

cd game_app
cat << src/main.c << _EOF
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

typedef struct App
{
  SDL_Window *window;
  SDL_Renderer *renderer;
} App;

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

_EOF

code .
```

My `Makefile`

```bash
CC = LIBRARY_PATH+="/opt/homebrew/lib" /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-13

BUILD_DIR = build/debug

SRC_DIR = src
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJ_NAME = shooter
INCLUDE_PATHS = -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/include/c++/13 -Iinclude
LIBRARY_PATHS = -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/13 -Llib
COMPILER_FLAGS = -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g
LINKER_FLAGS = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image

all: $(SRC_FILES)
    $(CC) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(SRC_FILES) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OBJ_NAME)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*
```

my `vscode` configuration

`.vscode/settings.json` file

```json
{
  "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser",
  "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "disabled",
  "C_Cpp.enhancedColorization": "enabled",
}
```

`.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Mac",
      "compilerPath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-13",
      "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-arm64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/include/c++/13",
        "${workspaceFolder}/include"
      ],
      "defines": [],
      "macFrameworkPath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "/System/Library/Frameworks",
        "/Library/Frameworks"
      ],
      "cStandard": "c17",
      "cppStandard": "c++17",
      "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools",
      "browse": {
        "path": [
          "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/include/c++/13",
          "${workspaceFolder}/include"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

`.vscode/launch.json` file

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/debug/shooter",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "lldb",
      "preLaunchTask": "build"
    }
  ]
}
```

`.vscode/tasks.json` file

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "build",
      "command": "make",
      "args": [],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": "build",
      "detail": "Build our program using make"
    }
  ],
}
```